# Comparing 2 arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to compare 2 arrays to see if an element in one array is in another array.

But i can't seem to get it to work

```
//if a categories checkbox is clicked
$j('#cat-dropdown li label input').click(function(e) {

    //Get all selected categories
    var categories = new Array;
    $j('#cat-dropdown li label input').each(function(index, element) {  
        if($j(this).is(':checked')){
            categories.push($j(this).val());
        }
    }); // Categories variable now has all selected cats


    $j('.products-grid li.item').each(function(index, element) {
        //get all the cateroies of a product
        console.log('//////////////////////'+$j(this).val())
        product_cats = $j(this).attr('data-product-categories').split(",");

        //Now check if the product categories is in the selected categories
        var inCategoryList = false;
        for (i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
            if($j.inArray(categories[i],product_cats)){
                console.log('test '+categories[i])
                inCategoryList = true;
            }
        }
        if(inCategoryList == false){
            $j(this).hide();
        }


    });//end each on product-grid li.item


});//end click function
```

But it is not working , nothing gets hidden.. But also the inArray method seems not be working properly, is there a different way to compare 2 arrays and check if one element is in another.

The basic flow is, user selects a checkbox, the li item has a list of categories attached to it. If the checkbox matches a category then keep the item displayed if there are no matches then hide it

Comment: `.inArray()` returns an index (where the item was found, or -1 if not), not a boolean.

Comment: Change your code asking if inArray returned -1. And check.